# How to mount EFS on ECS cluster Using the efsVolumeConfiguration task definition parameter Beta which was launched by AWS in Jan 2020

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

AWS provides this in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html)

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "container-using-efs",
            "image": "amazonlinux:2",
            "entryPoint": [
                "sh",
                "-c"
            ],
        "command": [
            "ls -la /mount/efs"
        ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "myEfsVolume",
                    "containerPath": "/mount/efs",
                    "readOnly": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "myEfsVolume",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-1234",
                "rootDirectory": "/path/to/my/data"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

i have created an EFS file system assigned it with the security group allowing inbound NFS and the EFS uses that security group and the subnet and VPC which my ECS cluster uses

**PROBLEM**

When i use the AWS management console to create a mount point in my task definition i have to enter the `containerPath` else `mountPoints` is not reflected in my JSON

**QUESTION**

1)What should my `containerPath` be under `mountPoints` ?

2)Should i specify a `rootDirectory` under `efsVolumeConfiguration` ?

**INFO**

1) I am running wordpress on my ECS cluster

2) I want persistent storage for my container that is why i am attempting to mount EFS

3) I want to map all of my wordpress files onto the EFS container so any changes i make are not reversed when the container restarts

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This question has been getting a lot of views.. so i wanted to help everyone out

So i mentioned how to use this feature in a blog i have posted here,

[Check step 4 to step 7 and step 8 to step 12](https://atom8.tech/blog/how-to-deploy-mqtt-broker-using-eclipse-mosquitto-on-amazon-ecs/)

This will give you a good idea of how to implement it practically in the `AWS Management console`

hope this helps the community :)

Comment: So no CloudFormation solution for it?

Comment: @StefanoMessina I'm not aware of any .. you can look it up or maybe create one based on my blog :)

Comment: It would be more helpful to actually post the answer to the question here, instead of just providing a link that may go 404.

Comment: Link is good, but we are looking for the solution in CFT

Answer (score 8):

The `containerPath` is the path you would like to use inside your docker container. In wordpress that could be for example '/var/www/html/htdocs/content/uploads'.
The `rootDirectory` is the path to the directory inside EFS you want to use.
An example where I have a folder `uploads` in my EFS:

```
"volumes": [
{
  "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
    "fileSystemId": "fs-xxxxxx",
    "rootDirectory": "/uploads"
}]
```

When you create your EFS target for the first time you don't have any folders inside it so then you have to use `/` as `rootDirectory`